# Is there any way through which i can embed Excel sheet into ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net

i need to know that is there any way through which i can embed Excel sheet into ASP.Net as i want to allow user to give multiple records at a time and then can use only single event to insert all those records into the database as i want to avoid event execution for every record

Comment: Are you really approaching the problem in right direction? If amount of data being inserted is big then you can give option of uploading excel sheet to your user in predefined format. Otherwise if it just about inserting small amount of data then it can be achieved using either jQuery Grid or HTML table + JS etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, This will read from data from your excel file and store into your database.

http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2976.aspx